# Why are these two Linq operations different?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Wasn't quite sure how to phrase the main question, but below are two versions of the same thing (at least in my mind).
The first always returns null, but the second returns the correct object.

Always null on return

```
var table = await DatabaseContext.Table
                   .Include(tb => tb.RefTable)
                   .Where(tb => tb.RefTable.Id == Id)
                   .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
                   .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Returns correct object

```
var List<Table> tableList = DatabaseContext.Table
                            .Include(tb => tb.RefTable).ToList()

var table = tableList
             .Where(tb => tb.RefTable.Id == Id)
             .First();
```

My main question really, is why?

EDIT --
Ok, here's the kicker, this is only an issue in a unittest environment, with a service collection and built service provider that supplies an in-memory dbcontext.

Comment: `DatabaseContext.Table.Include(tb => tb.RefTable).ToList()`, thats one big query you go there.  Every thing in table and RefTable

Comment: You may check what is the SQL generated underneath in the first case. Then check whether this SQL is correct or not

Comment: The second one is pulling the entire contents of the database table into C#, and then filtering in C#. The other one is changing your filter into part of the SQL query (where clause). As Renat says, you should check the query that's being generated for the first one.

Comment: Generated SQL for query that has `.Include` are not easly readable and understandable.

Comment: As of why they are producing different result - it seems they shouldn't be. But we can't really see the context in which your code is executing. For example, is the code inside a method that is returning `null` or "correct object"? Or, are you inspecting the value of `table` in debug mode? Your second code is executing synchronously. Try executing the first code synchronously too - without `await` and `ConfigureAwait(false)`, and with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @atiyar Same result.

Table is null with #1, table is the expected object with #2

Answer (score 0):

First one is the correct way, otherwise you will filter data on the client side. But probably there is problem that you filter by navigation property. It can be analyzed only if you compare the SQL.

So just try to avoid that:

```cs
var table = await DatabaseContext.Table
    .Include(tb => tb.RefTable)
    .Where(tb => tb.RefTableId == Id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: `Table` entity may not contain the `RefTableId` FK property.

Comment: It does not, but it could be added I suppose

Comment: @Beshman88 Yes it could be added, but my point is its absence shouldn't be the reason of how your query is behaving now.

Comment: @atiyar, accessing navigation like that always generate JOIN, that's why it is not effective.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes I agree, but the query is returning `null`, which cannot result from ineffectiveness :)

Comment: @atiyar, and again without SQL this discussion useless ;)